# Xtext cross referencing and scoping

Tags: reference, xtext, scoping

I have some problems with xtext cross referencing
Here is a very simple grammer:

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl1.Test with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals
generate test "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl1/Test"
Model: block=Block? cs+=Company* ; 
Block:  '{' g=[Employee] '}';
Company: 'Company' name=ID
    '{' es+= Employee* '}';
Employee: 'Employee' name=ID ';' ;
```

and it is my dsl :

```
{ Pooyan }
Company Sony{
    Employee Pooyan;
    Employee John;
}
```

It always shown that "Couldn't resolve reference to Employee 'Pooyan'."
Could anyone please help me?
I have no idea...

Answer (score 4):

The fully qualified name of Pooyan is Sony.Pooyan. Since the cross reference 'g' in your block is defined in another contain, you have to do a minor customizing to put it onto the scope.

1. If your language always uses a flat namespace, you could enable the SimpleNamesFragment in the language generator and remove the QualifiedNamesFragment. This should do the trick.
2. Alternatively, you could customize the scoping for the concrete reference 'g' in your scope provider.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Sebastians' answer to make it more precise: you need to change "fragment = exporting.QualifiedNamesFragment auto-inject {}" to "fragment = exporting.SimpleNamesFragment" in the corresponding .mwe2 file of your xtext project.

Hope this helps.